# Failed assertion error while trying to compile SV code

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog

```
module tb;
  string dialog = "HELLO";
  int i;
  initial
    begin
      for(i = 0; i < (dialog.len() - 1); i = i + 1) begin
        $display("%s",dialog[i]);
      end
    end
endmodule
```

I am trying to iterate through the string variable, but I'm getting the following error:

**assert: netmisc.cc:389: failed assertion indices.size()+1 == packed_dims.size()**

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce that error, but only with the `iverilog` simulator on EDA Playground (Icarus Verilog version 0.10.0).

[Using another simulator](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/n_vF), I don't get any errors, and I get this output:

```
H
E
L
L
```

I don't get the error with this `iverilog` version (which I presume is newer):

```
iverilog -V
Icarus Verilog version 10.3 (stable) (v10_3)
```

The problem is with your simulator.  You should try to upgrade it or switch to another simulator.